# How get 1 JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have 2 JFrame : A and B
from Screen A : call B as:

```
B b=new B();
b.setName("B1");
b.show();
```

and

```
 B b=new B();
    b.setName("B2");
    b.show();
```

The result: show 2 screen B is: B1 and B2
If from Screen A: i want set value for control of B1 or B2. How code?
Thanks?

Comment: no idea question in this form isn't answerable, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 2) I don't really understand the requirements.  3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). (And for everybody's sakes, choose more descriptive frame titles than `B1` & `B2` - they sound like characters for a children's show.)

Answer (score 2):

- use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead of creating two or more [JFrames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)
- use [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) with [patent to `JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20boolean%29) in the case that you have got real and important reasons to use another popup window, and/or with modality for mouse and key events

Comment: Can i get init of JFrame with Name of Screen?

Comment: right is possible, no issue, [but JFrame must be setVisible(true) and started on InitialThread (wraped in invokeLater)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), post an SSCCE